# How to use the field "email" as "username" in django?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models, django-views

Hello everyone I am new to django and I am creating a project where I created a database with a table "tblusuarios" and managed to insert the necessary data such as name, surname, email, password, however, when I go to make the login I am using the field "mail" as username, but so far fails to make the login. Any advice you can offer me?
User model:

```
class TblUsuarios(AbstractBaseUser, models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    correo = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    tbl_roles = models.ForeignKey(TblRoles, models.DO_NOTHING, default=1)

    # object = CustomAccountManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'correo' #le damos el username por defecto a la tabla
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=(['nombre'])
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tbl_usuarios'
```

View function:

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        correo = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(request, username = correo, password = password)
        print(user)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.info(request, 'Has ingresado correctamente a la aplicacion!!')
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Ha ocurrido un error a la hora de iniciar sesion!')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        context = {}
        return render(request, 'users/login.html', context)
```

Login form:

```
{% extends "layouts/layout.html" %} {% block content %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <h2>Ya estas logueado en nuestra aplicación</h2>
{% else %}

<section class="vh-100">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 text-black">
        <div
          class="d-flex align-items-center h-custom-2 px-5 ms-xl-4 mt-5 pt-5 pt-xl-0 mt-xl-n5"
        >
          <form style="width: 23rem" method="post" action="">
              {% csrf_token %}
            <h3 class="fw-normal mb-3 pb-3" style="letter-spacing: 1px">
              Log in
            </h3>

            <div class="form-outline mb-4">
              <input
                type="email"
                id="email"
                class="form-control form-control-lg"
                name="email"
              />
              <label class="form-label" for="email"
                >Correo</label
              >
            </div>

            <div class="form-outline mb-4">
              <input
                type="password"
                id="password"
                class="form-control form-control-lg"
                name="password"
              />
              <label class="form-label" for="password">Contraseña</label>
            </div>
            
            <div class="pt-1 mb-4">
                <input type="submit" value="Ingresar"  class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block">
            </div>

            <p class="small mb-5 pb-lg-2">
              <a class="text-muted" href="#!">Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a>
            </p>
            <p>
              No tienes una cuenta?
              <a href="/register/" class="link-info">Registrate acá</a>
            </p>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 px-0 d-none d-sm-block">
        <img
          src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-login-form/img3.webp"
          alt="Login image"
          class="w-100 vh-100"
          style="object-fit: cover; object-position: left"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

So as I say, always the variable "user" in the view function comes as "none".

I added the "USERNAME_FIELD" variable to my user model, however it did not work.

Comment: You shouldn't inherit both from `AbstractBaseUser` and `models.Model`. Only `AbstractBaseUser`. See example from Doc : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.USERNAME_FIELD

Comment: Have you specified [AUTH_USER_MODEL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you should not inherit both from `AbstractBaseUser` and `models.Model`. See working example from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.USERNAME_FIELD) :

Code sample :

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.db import models


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    ...
    USERNAME_FIELD = "identifier"
```

Also in your settings do not forget to precise the user model you want to use with the `AUTH_USER_MODEL`, reference [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

In your `settings.py` :

```py
# ...
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "path.to.your.model.YourCustomUserModel"
# ...
```

Comment: Hello! I made the change and exported the migrations just in case but still no authentication in the login.

Comment: @juan You should also point to that model in your settings with the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` settings. See reference here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better this way. I do it like this, but I don't know about the login part because I write it differently. Please do it this way, and if it doesn't work, let me know here.

```
from mymodel import TblUsuarios

def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        correo = request.POST.get['email']
        password = request.POST.get['password']
        if correo != '' and password != ''
            if TblUsuarios.objects.filter('email' = email).exists():            #If the email was in the database 
                TblUsuariosObject = TblUsuarios.objects.get('email' = email)    #Get Object with entered email
                if TblUsuariosObject.password == password:                      #check this email password == password in input
                    print(TblUsuariosObject.correo)
        # user = authenticate(request, username = correo, password = password)
        # print(user)
        # if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    messages.info(request, 'Has ingresado correctamente a la aplicacion!!')
                    return redirect('home')
                else:
                    messages.error(request, 'Ha ocurrido un error a la hora de iniciar sesion!')
                    return redirect('login')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'dont have this email in the Database')
                return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Null Inputs')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        context = {}
        return render(request, 'users/login.html', context)
```

Comment: I did it this way but the solution was to add the line "AUTH_USER_MODEL = "webapp.TblUsers"" to settings.py. Thanks for your answer